# How to disable GPS info from programming while taking picture/video on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, camera

I do not want GPS information to be incorporated in the pictures/videos taken by our app, I could not find any api to disable GPS location information while using camera. I know user can enable disable it by going in settings etc, but I want to turn off GPS only for my app automatically so any camera (video/picture) should not use GPS at all.

Comment: I'm struggling to get my app to add the GPS. Have you verified your app is actually saving this data and is it using the photo picker (which can choose between the camera roll or the actual camera) or an AVCaptureSession which is what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the gps info to 0? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806729/objective-c-adding-gps-information-to-a-photograph