# Objective-C - Adding GPS information to a photograph

Tags: iphone, ios, image, gps, exif

I am wondering if it is possible to add GPS information to a photograph when saving the item to the camera roll.

The code I currently use to save the image is:

```
UIImage *theImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(theImage, self, 
                                       @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

I am wondering how I can modify the image EXIF data to add the current location, and make it compatible with the 'Places' functionality on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example: http://caffeinatedcocoa.com/blog/?p=7 explains how to update the date of a photo. Go to [CGImageProperties Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html) and do the same replacing the key kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeDigitized of the example with the relevant GPS keys. I haven't try this myself, but sounds like it should work. :)